# Angular Material not working (everything included)

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

well i have website cut on parts, but i included inside css inside head tag and js in body but it does not works anyway 
http://i.imgur.com/V7B7x5p.png - setup
and i also have done this:

```
<html ng-app="StarterApp">
```

but it does not work eaither, but on simple web it works 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiwBx.png -> Working Version, on this screen shown code works, but its only test site

Answer (score 2):

You need to load your angular-material.min.js file before the js.js file where you call ngMaterial. Moving the angular-material.min.js file above js.js in your HTML should fix the problem.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. You just need to load js.js after angular and all of your angular modules/dependencies. Your code should look like this:
`<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="js.js"></script>` with js.js loaded last.

Comment: doing exactly same thing, screen shown above its a WORKING website, well i wrote it worked on simple web, the screen shows a working version but here`s load order of web that does not works
http://i.imgur.com/shAn6dd.png